# Mongoose update variable with sum of old and new

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update new `balance` of user with summing old one using only **update** method.

```
users.update({user_id: 12345}, {balance: balanceFromFunc+oldBalance});
```

Are there any easy way to do this? Or do I have to do it like this? :

```
users.where(.... err, docs){
  var oldBalance = users.docs.balance ;
  var newBalance = "somevalue";
  var NEW_Balance = newBalance + oldBalance;
  users.update(...,balance : NEW_BALANCE)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$inc` operator
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

```
users.update({user_id: 12345}, { $inc: { balance: balanceFromFunc } });
```